# Multiple tables Not IN Filling with Nulls

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

**Table 1:**  `batch_info with columns  batch_id, brew_date, beer_style_name`

**Table 2:**  `brew_fermentation with columns batch_id (FK of batch_info), fermentor_name (FK of fermentor),.`.

**Table 3:**  `fermentor with columns, fermentor_name, tank_volume`

**Table 4:**  `Produced_amount with columns batch_id(FK of batch_info), produced_amount, date_transferred`

When a beer is brewed we enter it into Table 1 and Table 2,  When the beer is done fermenting we then enter the data into table 4 produced_amount.

I would like to create is a table that looks something like this

```
Fermentor # |  Batch_ID  |  Tank_Size  |  Date_Brewed  | Beer Style

F10.1           13001         10           2013-01-12      IPA

F20.2           NULL         20             NULL          EMPTY
```

I have the following SQL statement.

However it will not show all of the fermentors from the fermentor table only the ones that currently have something in them.  I would like to populate the the table like above.

```
SELECT brew_fermentation.fermentor_name AS "Fermentor #",
batch_info.batch_id AS "Batch Number", batch_info.beer_style_name AS
"Beer Style", batch_info.date_brewed AS "Date Brewed",
fermentor.tank_volume AS "BBLs"

FROM batch_info, fermentor, brew_fermentation

WHERE batch_info.batch_id = brew_fermentation.batch_id AND
brew_fermentation.fermentor_name=fermentor.fermentor_name AND

batch_info.batch_id NOT IN (SELECT produced_amount.batch_id FROM
produced_amount)

ORDER BY batch_info.date_brewed
```

Comment: The below answer returned the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`.

```
  ...
WHERE 
  batch_info.batch_id = brew_fermentation.batch_id 
  AND brew_fermentation.fermentor_name=fermentor.fermentor_name 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM produced_amount WHERE batch_id = batch_info.batch_id
  )
```